# Ethereum Master Account not holding Coins of all its generated accounts

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I tried to use HD wallet and generate new accounts but i want all of my Coins of new accounts to store in master account. 
**Is it possible in ethereum?**

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're a little bit confused about what the HD wallet's purpose is for.

Let me simplify it...

Let's take a look at how managing keys worked prior to `bip32`. Let's say, you wanted to create 100 wallets:

```
seed1 +----> pk1 +----> addr1
seed2 +----> pk2 +----> addr2
...
seed100 +--> pk100 +--> addr100
```

So, in order to manage/backup the keys you'd have to store each one in some secure ways, but the thing is, you had to back every single one of them. if you lose one the funds are lost.

In HD-wallet it looks like this:

```
                   +--> child key1 +--> grandchild key1,2,3... +--> addr1,2,3
                   |
seed +----> master +--> child key2 +--> grandchild key1,2,3... +--> addr1,2,3
             key   |
                   +--> child key3 +--> grandchild key1,2,3... +--> addr1,2,3
```

You'd only need to store the single seed. Now, this is quite the simplified version i'm leaving out the many other possibilities of the `hd-wallet` such as possibility to handle multi-coin in `bip44`

So back to your original question...
Every single address generated by your `hd-wallet` will work just like every other addresses on the network. It's just your pk generation/managing method that's seems different on your end.

Also Ethereum doesn't support that kind of funneling of funds to the "master" address. You could implement it on a `smartcontract`. But still, every address have to pay their own fees to interact with the `smartcontract`.